# Light weight alternative to Hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, sqlite

I have a single user java program that I would like to have store data in a light weight database such as Derby or Sqlite. I would like to use a data abstraction layer in my program. Hibernate appears to require a lot of configuration and is overkill for what I need. What are light weight alternatives to Hibernate?

Comment: You can check alternatives along with example usage (and example configuration with Spring) here: https://github.com/bwajtr/java-persistence-frameworks-comparison

Comment: CMobileCom JPA is a light-weight JPA implementation for both Java and Android. Its size is about 380K. It is light and fast.  https://cmobilecom.com

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Hibernate requires next to zero configuration if you use annotations. It even can auto-discover mapped beans in the classpath! I don't see any alternative to it from both simplicity **and** power point of view.

It can also expose itself as JPA, which is (IMHO) even simpler.

Comment: Hibernate works pretty well with Derby - it was very simple to migrate my Eclipse RCP application fromSQL Server to embedded Derby. If you're using annotations the amount of configuration is in fact quite small.

Comment: next to zero is not zero.

Comment: also it needs a lot external libraries try to use it on android :P

Comment: I tried to find a simpler alternative to Hibernate.  In a personal project, I used MyBatis (what a terrible name).  It was much more work than Hibernate.  Hibernate really saves a lot of SQL coding and helps with parent-child relationships.  I also looked at a few ActiveRecord style ORM's for Java.  None seemed mature or any easier than Hibernate.  So, I'm going back to Hibernate.

Comment: was the question not about an ALTERNATIVE?

Comment: Hibernate is not a lightweight alternative to Hiberernate

Comment: Using direct mapping with the objects assumes this can be done, using inversion the mapping xml is pretty heavy with hibernate. Hibernate can also be problematic with its proxy objects that also add objects onto the heap. Often a simpler alternative is required simply using JdbcTemplate and a field mapping strategy.

Comment: If you want to use Hibernate in android app, it is too heavy obviously. Now there is a light weight JPA implementation available for Android and Java - "CMobileCom JPA". It is light-weight(about 380K) and fast. Check it out at https://cmobilecom.com.

Comment: Hibernate is not lightweight by any measure. I actually wrote about  it some time ago: http://igorpolevoy.blogspot.com/2012/04/just-how-thin-can-framework-be.html

Answer (score 58):

My [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) library is one such alternative. It supports MySQL, Postgres, Microsoft SQL Server, H2, Derby, HSQLDB, and Sqlite, and can be easily extended to others.  It uses annotations to configure classes, good Spring support, flexible query builder, etc..

Comment: OrmLite really looks promising! But is this project still alive? No new version for over a year, no answer to pull requests/issues on Github.

Comment: Version 5.0 was released in June 2016.

Comment: Version 5.1 was released on 2/19/2018. But is not comparable to Hibernate at all and some JPA annotation implementation doesn't work properly.

Comment: "comparable to Hibernate"?  They are both ORMs but otherwise vastly different.  In terms of JPA implementations, pls fill out a bug report if you find something @M-Razavi.

Answer (score 32):

It still requires XML configuration, but have a look at [MyBatis (formerly iBatis)](https://mybatis.org).

Comment: iBatis is very lightweight. You can more easily define and control your SQL to object mapping.

Comment: ... have to throw a vote for iBatis, though mind you it's not an ORM alternative as it is not trying to compete with likes of Hibernate. It's a bit different sort of an animal, but fits what you're looking for in terms of weight.

Comment: Now it's MyBatis that's left: http://www.mybatis.org/

Comment: I think the XML in i/MyBatis is actually an advantage since it keeps complicated queries in a format which can be easily copied to an SQL console for testing.

Answer (score 24):

[jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) ships with a fluent DSL simulating SQL directly in Java as a side-effect for its main goals which are:

- Source code generation
- Full support for standard SQL including SQL language features such as UNIONs, nested SELECTs, all types of JOINs, aliasing (e.g. for self-joins), etc
- Wide support for non-standard SQL including UDT's, stored procedures, vendor-specific functions, etc.

Read about jOOQ in this article: http://java.dzone.com/announcements/simple-and-intuitive-approach, or visit the website directly: http://www.jooq.org

(Disclaimer, I work for the company behind jOOQ)

Comment: jOOQ rocks!  We implemented a large scale ETL service with it, and couldn't be happier.  I've used iBATIS, and jOOQ gives all the same advantages of low level SQL without the reams of XML and lack of type safety.

Comment: I forgot to mention one of the best features of jOOQ: Complex and/or dynamically generated queries can be assembled in a controlled way and verified by the Java compiler, saving you from all those ambiguous syntax errors databases throw, and providing compile-time regression coverage for when the schema changes under you.

Comment: JOOQ is amazing but obviously its now not free to Oracle and Sybase so lot of people are avoiding this framework and are using like MyBatis

Comment: @Makky: Thanks for your feedback. I do hope that you're keeping actual value propositions in mind, and that you're not going to be switching to a completely different framework just based on the fact that one is free and the other is not. The cost of maintenance and migration this would induce in *your* software is prohibitive and far beyond any reasonable commercial license...

Answer (score 16):

[Apache Commons DBUtils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/) takes much of the repetitive gruntwork out of JDBC programming.  It requires little configuration and is easy to learn.  It is not an ORM framework (in the way that Hibernate and other frameworks mentioned here are) but it does automate mapping of SELECT columns to Java member fields as well as other repetitive JDBC programming tasks.  It's certainly lightweight.

Answer (score 12):

You can have a look at [Ebean ORM](http://ebean-orm.github.io/). 
- No sessions
- lazy loading just works
- Simpler API to use and learn.

Comment: is it compatible with SQLite and Android?

Comment: SQLite support has been added. I haven't tried it on Android yet.

Answer (score 9):

[Cayenne](http://cayenne.apache.org/) has served me well. Relatively easy to understand and to get it up and running. I find the reverse engineering part particularly charming. Configuration can be done with a GUI.

Answer (score 6):

I can propose apache empire-db. http://incubator.apache.org/empire-db/

Apache Empire-db is an Open Source relational data persistence component which allows database vendor independent dynamic query definition as well as safe and simple data retrieval and updating. Compared to most other solutions like e.g. Hibernate, TopLink, iBATIS or JPA implementations, Empire-db takes a considerably different approach, with a special focus on ***compile-time safety***, reduced redundancies and improved developer productivity.

An example:

```
// Define the query
DBCommand cmd = db.createCommand();
DBColumnExpr EMPLOYEE_FULLNAME= db.EMPLOYEES.LASTNAME.append(", ")
                        .append(db.EMPLOYEES.FIRSTNAME).as("FULL_NAME");
// Select required columns
cmd.select(db.EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_FULLNAME);
cmd.select(db.EMPLOYEES.GENDER, db.EMPLOYEES.PHONE_NUMBER);
cmd.select(db.DEPARTMENTS.NAME.as("DEPARTMENT"));
cmd.select(db.DEPARTMENTS.BUSINESS_UNIT);
// Set Joins
cmd.join(db.EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID, db.DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID);
// Set contraints and order
cmd.where(EMP.LASTNAME.length().isGreaterThan(0));
cmd.orderBy(EMP.LASTNAME);;
```

Answer (score 3):

ORMAN framework is also good. https://github.com/ahmetalpbalkan/orman

Documentation: https://github.com/ahmetalpbalkan/orman/wiki

Comparison: https://github.com/ahmetalpbalkan/orman/wiki/Why-orman-is-better-than-other-orms-for-you%3F

Comment: This one should be all the way at the top. It rocks !

Answer (score 3):

I might be a bit late to the party, but I released [ActiveJDBC](http://javalite.io/activejdbc/)  in 2010, which is an ORM implementation of ActiveRecord pattern, is more than 10 times lighter than Hibernate in dependencies, at least twice as fast at run time, and requires zero configuration or annotations.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at prevayler (on sourceforge). A somewhat more lightweight approach to persistence. Or were you thinking about doing reporting against the DB?

Answer (score 1):

If using a relational database is not mandatory, give db4o a try.

Answer (score 1):

I created [sormula](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sormula/) as an alternative to heavyweight ORM's. It is CRUD-ready, POJO-friendly, simple to use, configure, and understand. Zero-configuration use is possible. [www.sormula.org](http://www.sormula.org)

Answer (score -2):

Kiteframework is also very light orm framework. It provides almost all db operation with minimal configurations.

http://deipakgarg.github.com/Kite-ORM/

**Disclosure: I am the author of this project**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: it's not in development, no new current release from the author, last expected release was in 2012.