# hibernate restore deleted entities

Tags: hibernate, restore, recycle-bin

Is there a third-party library which add restore deleted entities feature? i need something like Hibernate envers which creates entities and map them to tables at runtime, but a lot simpler! i just need two tables for each entity so that when the entity was deleted it would be moved to the other table.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a simpler approach is to never allow anything to be deleted from the table.  Instead just have a `deleted INT(1) DEFAULT 0` column that specifies whether or not a row has been deleted.  Then you can easily get a list of all rows/entities that have been deleted, and undelete any/all that you want by just clearing the `deleted` flag.

The nice thing about such an approach is that it is ORM-agnostic.  You can choose any desired [lightweight alternative to Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296587/light-weight-alternative-to-hibernate) that you like, and they will all play nicely with this kind of technique.  The downside is that you have to do a bit of manual work to get the undelete functionality implemented.

Comment: it is not efficient, the table may have 1m entries but just the 10 valid entities. the other problem is when i want to delete the entity, db constraints are not checked...