# Filestructure when developing for android

Tags: android, model-view-controller

I'm new to developing on android and I wonder how you organize your android projects?
I have done a whole bunch of projects in ruby on rails lately, so is there a possibility to use a MVC-style approach?

Comment: MVC is already build try to make some project and you will see :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you surely can use a MVC pattern, meaning you will make a different class for the `activity`, a class for the `view` objects and a class for some "controller" objects. Also, MVC is implemented in many Java library classes, so is preatty handy that you do well with this pattern.

I'll give you an example: the `ListView` implements this pattern and you will be able to model the data separatelly from the layout and front-end.

Comment: Does it exist a ORM-library also?

Comment: Well, there is [ActiveAndroid](https://www.activeandroid.com/)(though not free) or if you are looking for some lightweight of Hibernate you could try [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296587/light-weight-alternative-to-hibernate)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this posting here: [MVC pattern on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925054/mvc-pattern-in-android)